# Changing a common 'key': 'value' to float from string in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, command-line-interface

I have a table filled with items that currently have this format.

{
  'low': '107.4200',
  'date': '2019-01-25 11:30:00',
  'symbol': 'MSFT',
  'open': '107.4800',
  'volume': '107897',
  'high': '107.4900',
  'close': '107.4550'
}

I am aiming to update all items in this table to make the value 'string' numbers for low, open, volume, high and close turn into actual floating point numbers.

I am looking for a command line interface solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to write something to scan all items from the table, then for each item execute an update to change each attribute.

Comment: this is correct - it might be easier to simply scan the original table and write to a new table in the new format; then deprecate/delete the old table.